# Verizon Galaxy Nexus Discharging When Plugged In Even After USB Replacement

Tags: usb, samsung-galaxy-nexus, battery, charging

I've got a Verizon Samsung Galaxy Nexus that as of a few weeks ago quit charging - in fact it quickly drains the battery (discharges 2% / minute if not more) while plugged in. I tried different batteries, cords, chargers, over USB, etc, no difference. I went ahead and followed [these instructions](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repairing+Samsung+Galaxy+Nexus+%28Verizon+LTE%29+Micro+USB+Charge+Port+%26+Main+Mic/9641/1) to replace the Micro USB port and I'm still having the same issue. The interesting thing is that computers recognize the phone via USB but the battery still shows "Discharging" and the battery drains extremely quickly. I have even tried charging via the pins on the side of the phone ("pogo pins" charging) and exhibits the same symptoms as traditional charging. This leads me to believe the charging circuit itself is damaged, instead of just the USB port.

Anyone have any tips or references on what else to troubleshoot or have any specs on the charging circuit itself that I could poke around with? I have a decent amount of electronics knowledge and don't mind getting my hands dirty. I am getting by with spare batteries and an external battery charger right now, but it is quite a hassle.

Comment: Take it back to your carrier's shop as its faulty! :) Nothing can be done from asking in here.

Comment: Is it a third party charger, or an OEM model?

Comment: You probably already have a new phone or know the answer, but I agree with the charging circuit idea. Did you replace the port or the whole charging circuit board?

Comment: @t0mm13b OP clearly says about replacing microUSB port himself. Are you really sure, that carrier's shop will accept faulty phone, if it was modified by user himself? What about warranty?